# Django can't eliminate duplicated entries with set (mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, django, list, filter

I have a list `a` on the code, and i want to eliminate duplicated entries.
I saw a very clean method here: http://love-python.blogspot.pt/2008/09/remove-duplicate-items-from-list-using.html
i am using mysql

But when i acesss the page i get this error: `'list' object has no attribute 'all'` i can't figure where this is coming from!

`forms.py`:

```
from testApp.models import Ficha_medico
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django    import forms

class MenuForm(ModelForm):
    a = Ficha_medico.objects.values_list('zona', flat=True)
    a = list (set(a))
    zona = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=a)
    class Meta:
        model = Ficha_medico
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you where it is coming from.

A list is not a queryset. You can't pass it as the queryset parameter of a field.

To eliminate duplicates in a queryset, use `.distinct()`.

Comment: i get this error: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: on django docs says that you can only specify fiels using PostgreSQL i am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

`.values_list()` returns a `list` object, not a queryset.

Apparently, something like this would work if you're using PostgreSQL:

```
a = Ficha_medico.objects.distinct('zona')
```

For others, I suspect there's a better way, but this would work:

```
class MenuForm(ModelForm):
    items = Ficha_medico.objects.values_list(('id', 'zona'), flat=True)
    # get a single 'id' per 'zona'
    # --> since we don't know how many there are cycle through all
    # --> note: this will overwrite existing values, but doesn't seem to matter.
    uniques = {z: i for i, z in items}

    # re-query to retrieve only the necessary number of unique zona values
    qs = Ficha_medico.objects.filter(id__in=uniques.values())

    zona = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=qs)
    class Meta:
        model = Ficha_medico
```

Comment: i get this error: `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`

Comment: on django docs says that you can only specify fiels using PostgreSQL